# Find $x_0$ that satifies $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x_0) = 0.75$

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

> Suppose that $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function:
> $$\begin{cases} 
> x   & 0 \leq x < 1, \\[6pt]
> 2-x & 1 \leq x < 2, \\[6pt]
> 0   & \text{otherwise}. \\[6pt]
> \end{cases}$$
> Find $x_0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x_0) = 0.75$.

My initial thought was that this is basically asking me to equate the CDF to 0.75 and solve for $x$.  I also realized that this PDF is a triangle so integrating it would just be the area of a triangle with $h = 1$ and trying to find how long the base should be. By doing so I get that $b = 1.5$

However my Professor's answer is different.  The Professor use the fact that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq x_0) = 0.75 \implies \frac{1}{2} \times (2 - x_0) \times 1 \times (2-x_0) = 1 - 0.75$$

to get the solution $x_0 = 2 - 1/\sqrt{2}$.  I'm wondering if anybody can explain where I went wrong in my thinking and why the Professor's answer is correct, and how they came about their answer.

Comment: It looks like your reasoning is sound but you made a geometric error in finding $b.$  You can verify that by checking your answer: what is the area under the pdf to the right of $b=1.5$?  It ought to equal $1-0.75=0.25.$  The issue is that the region to the left of $b$ is not a triangle.  As always, *draw a picture.*

Comment: This clearly needs the `self-study` tag, so rather than argue about it,-I'm putting it in.